# how to view Application Support folder in the Macintosh Finder

Tags: finder

Using the Macintosh Finder to navigate to Library / Application Support gives folders such as Apple and ApplePushService.

Using the Macintosh Terminal app to navigate to Library / Application Support seems to give a different folder without foldes such as ApplePushService.

It seems the Finder is showing a different "Application Support" folder.

How can I display the folder seen in the Terminal app in the Finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Terminal.app**, run this following code.  Then once **Finder** reveals the folder, just drag the folder to your sidebar in **Finder** so you can easily navigate to it in the future.

`open -R "Library/Application Support"`    *(User's App Support folder)*

If you want to reveal the Application Support folder which contains the ApplePushService folder, then use this code...

`open -R "/Library/Application Support"` *(System's App Support folder)*